# Constructor function to create DOM elements

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to use a constructor function to help create DOM elements but I'm wondering if there was a preferred way to do so. I know I could use a framework to do with this but I'd like to implement it using vanilla JavaScript.

Both ways shown below seem to work but I haven't used the `new` operator with functions very much. Is there any difference between the two ways? Would I be better just to use a plain old function in this situation and not use `new`?

```
// First way
function Title(text){
  this.element = document.createElement('h2');
  this.element.innerText = text;
  return this.element;
}

// Second way
function Title(text){
  var element = document.createElement('h2');
  element.innerText = text;
  return element;
}

var title = new Title("Hello");
document.body.appendChild(title);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first way does't seem to be correct. Though it works, you seems you haven't understood how `new` works in JavaScript. When you use `new` with a function, the following steps are taken:

- An empty object is created, something like `{}`.
- All `this` references inside the function refer to that empty object.
- `this` is used to populate that empty object as needed.
- *implicitly* `this` is returned. (If you *explicitly* return, `this` will be ignored.)

Note that in a constructor function, if you *explicitly* return something other than `this`, the returned value is not `instanceof` that constructor function. Only `this` is `instanceof` the constructor function.

Therefore, the first way has nothing to do with logic of `new`. It's logically the same as the second one.